# When is a free submodule $N$ of a free module $M$ the set of solutions of a system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, systems-of-equations, free-modules

Suppose one has a (commutative) ring $R$ and a free $R$-module $M$ of rank $n$. Let $N \subset M$ be a free $R$-submodule of $M$. Of course, in general, it is not true that $N$ is the set of solutions of a system of linear equations (take for instance $M$ to be the $\mathbb Z$-module $M=\mathbb Z$, and $N = 2\mathbb Z$).

I was wondering the following:
If $rk(N) = n-k$, what are conditions on $N$, such that $N$ is the set of solutions of $k$ linear equations inside $M$?

The example above shows that this is not true unconditionally. The problem with the example seems to be that $M/N$ is not torsion free as a $\mathbb Z$-module.

So I think that a necessary condition is that $M/N$ is a torsion free $R$-module. Is it also sufficient?

Comment: Yes, torsion freeness is sufficient (am assuming that $R$ is a domain, since otherwise, torsion fee is a bit more ambiguous). Any finitely generated torsion free module of rank $k$ over such an $R$ can be embedded into a free module of rank $k$.

Comment: Thank you @Mohan. Do you have a source (or a proof, if it's short) for this? What about the case if $R$ is not a domain, for instance $R = \mathbb Z/d$? My understanding of "torsion free" means that there is no non-zero element in the module which becomes equal to zero after multiplying it with a non-zero divisor (or zero itself).

Comment: The proof is very easy and I suggest you try it. Your definition of torsion freeness is correct, but with that definition, rank itself is a bit ambiguous and there are modules which can not be realized as submodules of free modules.